# Повтор частицы БЫ при наличии союза ЧТОБЫ

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильность повтора частицы БЫ мне  хотелось бы рассмотреть на недавнем примере  из ЕГЭ: «Пусть во все времена на Руси растут богатыри такие, чтобы никто и никогда не смог бы побороть Россию и даже думать об этом не мог».  Является ли частица БЫ в данном случае избыточной, или она имеет определенную смысловую нагрузку?

Также для сравнения можно привести примеры с различным решением подобной задачи:

А) Мне надо, чтобы каждое слово, каждая фраза попадала БЫ в тон, к месту (Короленко). Сидите здесь на скамейке одна и умоляйте его, чтобы он отпустил вас на свободу, дал дышать воздухом, ушёл БЫ из памяти! (Булгаков)

Б) Все на свете должно происходить медленно и неправильно, чтобы не сумел загордиться человек, чтобы человек был грустен и растерян (Ерофеев). Мне хотелось, чтобы Осип Эмильевич разделял мое настроение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считаю в приведенных случаях излишней частицу БЫ. Это ненужный повтор одного и того же элемента. Этого требует и так называемый закон экономии языковых средств, и стремление к благозвучию. Нагромождение БЫ БЫ БЫ режет слух. Помнится, этим лишним Бы любил злоупотреблять известный политик Е.Примаков, и это резало слух.

Comment: Вы считаете, что и у классиков в приведенных примерах повтор частицы БЫ является избыточным? Кстати, пример из  Короленко Розенталь приводит вроде бы как правильный.А неправильно: "Если бы предложения западных держав были бы приняты, положение могло бы измениться».«Было выражено пожелание, чтобы контакты получили бы свое дальнейшее развитие»

Comment: На мой взгляд, Д.Э. Розенталь коллекционировал нелепости тоже.

Comment: Я думаю, примеры из классики нужно анализировать, учитывая контекст и исторические условия (я имею в виду условия существования языка), а не брать изолированное предложение.

Answer (score 0):

Пример из ЕГЭ: "...не смог (бы??)..." - частица "бы" явно избыточна, но её постановку в данном случае следует оправдать разве только требованием придания фразе элегантности звучания,  музыкальности. Классики - это люди с огромным, может быть, непререкаемым чувством языка. Поэтому в А) все "бы"поставлены к месту и являются музыкально оправданными. В варианте Б) с точки зрения музыкальности фразу Ерофеева следовало бы подкорректировать: "...чтобы был он грустен и растерян" (несмотря на соседство слогов "бы"!). Но... Ерофеев может не согласиться с этим! И последняя фраза: "Мне бы хотелось, чтобы..." - на мой взгляд, звучит музыкальнее и интеллигентнее, чем исходное предложение

Comment: По поводу "Мне бы хотелось, чтобы..." В Русской грамматике существует понятие о переносном (прагматическом) значении  сослагательного наклонения, при котором  СМЯГЧАЕТСЯ  заявление о намерениях говорящего или СНИЖАЕТСЯ КАТЕГОРИЧНОСТЬ утверждения - обычно для выражения желания, совета, рекомендации, вопроса. Например:"Мне не хотелось бы говорить о своем литературном опыте". "Я бы вам очень посоветовал сейчас ничего не хотеть и никого не видеть".А почему бы им не пожить две недели в Москве?" Наше предложение, по-видимому, из этой темы, поэтому и звучит интеллигентнее.

Comment: Почти не раздумывая, торопливо соглашаюсь с Вами (а если без "торопливо" нужна ли запятая? - не из разряда ли: "Подписал не читая"?)

Answer (score 0):

Хотя эта тема не вызвала большого интереса у участников форума, мне хотелось бы  высказать некоторые   свои мысли (пусть хотя бы гости почитают).

Вот Розенталь считает, что  частица БЫ в предложениях с  союзом ЧТОБЫ является избыточной. И действительно, во многих случаях  это однозначно определяется на слух. И в то же время существуют предложения, где БЫ  кажется вполне уместной, и это решение мы называем авторской интуицией. А что если попробовать заглянуть на авторскую кухню?

Пример 1:  «Мне надо, чтобы каждое слово, каждая фраза попадала бы в тон, к месту».  Думаю, что здесь в придаточном предложении частица БЫ обозначает некую  «добавочную виртуальность» действия, которое становится  реальным при  определенных условиях.  В этом случае  высказывание можно дополнить следующим образом: Мне надо, чтобы каждое слово, каждая фраза попадала бы в тон, к месту (ЕСЛИ Я БУДУ ЧТО-ЛИБО ПИСАТЬ).

Примерно такой же смысл я вижу и в нашем примере 2: Пусть во все времена растут на Руси богатыри такие, чтобы никто и никогда не смог  бы побороть Россию (ЕСЛИ КТО-ЛИБО ЗАХОЧЕТ НАПАСТЬ НА НАС).   Поэтому частица БЫ  мне здесь не кажется лишней.

Таким образом, получается, что союз ЧТОБЫ выражает  желательность действия, а частица БЫ  имеет  ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНОЕ УСЛОВНОЕ значение – неназванное, но понятное из текста.

Вообще говоря, общая теория сослагательного наклонения и сложна, и интересна, но мы предпочитаем не задумываться над тем, правильно ли мы употребляем частицу БЫ и что она в каждом конкретном случае обозначает.

Comment: Мне думается, что в Примере 1 более уместно разместить "бы" (противу правил) в первой части предложения: "Мне бы надо,...", перенеся виртуальную частицу из конца в начало предложения. Обоснование? Лучшая музыкальность фразы, подчёркнутость необходимости искусственного переноса частицы в начало, потому что в конце предложения она почти незаметна, слишком далека она от "чтобы", как декабристы от народа, по выражению В. И. Ленина. Это почти равносильно: "Мне бы хотелось,...". А вообще - Ваш комментарий очень разумен! Заставляет задуматься.

Comment: "Мне надо, чтобы..." - это твердое намерение автора, вряд ли он захотел бы его смягчить с помощью частицы БЫ. И большое спасибо за понимание. "Счастье - это когда тебя понимают". А также у Тютчева: "И нам сочувствие дается, как нам дается благодать"