# Союз ЧТОБЫ и частица БЫ

Tags: грамматика

Даны три варианта предложения:

(1) Как бы прожить жизнь так, **чтобы** не врать самому себе и черное не становилось белым, а белое - черным.

(2) Как бы прожить жизнь так, **чтобы** не врать самому себе и черное не становилось **бы** белым, а белое - черным.

(3) Как бы прожить жизнь так, **чтобы** не врать самому себе и **чтобы** черное не становилось белым, а белое - черным.

Какой вариант правильный и в каком учебнике можно посмотреть эту тему?

Comment: Для начала вот здесь. http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30915 Если недостаточно, то уточните вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, но там обсуждалась немного другая грамматическая конструкция, здесь же СПП с однородными придаточными. Меня интересует второе из них: там обязательно должен быть  союз ЧТОБЫ, или можно использовать частицу  БЫ,  или вообще допускается их отсутствие? И хотелось бы этот материал посмотреть в каком-нибудь официальном источнике.

Comment: Да там как бы все есть.  А разговоры то про учебник, то про "официальный источник" сильно настораживают. Устав караульной службы, что ли?

Comment: Там в одном предложении встречаются союз ЧТОБЫ и частица БЫ (обсуждается их избыточность), а здесь во втором из однородных придаточных вообще нет союза ЧТОБЫ. Так повтор союза обязателен, можно обойтись без него или это будет нарушением грамматики (стиля)?

Comment: Можете прочитать здесь: [4.6 Употребление сослагательного наклонения в придаточных цели](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#46)

Comment: К сожалению,  ссылка не открывается.

Comment: Ссылка-то открывается, но там ничего по теме поатора союза "бы". Общие слова про сослагательное наклонение.